# How to 'associate' a textbox to a group in SSRS 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2, and want to be able to 'associate' my text boxes to certain groups. You can do this in Cognos Impromptu.

Below is how the report looks in Cognos, with the association:

[image]

As you can see, it is grouped by Item Code, Item Description and then by Rack No which provides the breakdown of item counts in each rack.

You will then notice Item Count Qty is 'associated' with the stock item code group, and does not get repeated as a subgroup of each rack number. So the report essentially digs down into the racks, but then continues displaying fields at a higher group parent (stock item code).

How can this be done in SSRS? The only thing close i've found is adjacent groups but that puts the row group below, rather on the same row.

Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "puts the row group below"? Check out this, I think it is what you want: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170712.aspx

Comment: I mean it will create a seperate group instance on the row below the current grouping. There is no mention of how to do this in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SSRS, there is no concept of "associating" values with groups. This is handled by their position in the table/matrix. In other words, any cell that falls within the scope of a group is filtered by it. So a `Count` function will give different results depending on where it is in relation to the groups. If you want to override the default scope, you have to specify that in an expression.

If you need to reference values that are in a combination of other groups, you can either reference a textbox or add calculated fields to your dataset that get the values at that scope.

Comment: Thanks - i did suspect this was the case but wanted to be certain.